# run cygwin terminal using vb

Tags: vb.net

i need a code to type and perform commands in cygwin terminal in hidden mode(background) using visual basic, i was using cmd but now i want to use a Linux source code so i must use linux.
 i ran cmd in hidden mode successfully but it isn't working with cygwin, here is the cmd code:
`Shell("cmd.exe /k tracert -h  " & _h & " " & domain.Text & " > temp" & i + 1 & ".txt & exit", AppWinStyle.Hide, True)`

so i have tried

`Shell(""C:\cygwin\Cygwin.bat -k tracert -h  " & _h & " " & domain.Text & " > temp" & i + 1 & ".txt & exit", AppWinStyle.Hide, True)`

and

`Shell("C:\cygwin\Cygwin.bat")
'SendKeys.Send("tracert -h " & _h & " " & domain.Text & " > temp" & i + 1 & ".txt"))`

but this still didn't work where in the second code i still have to press enter in cygwin to process the traceroute and which should be automaticcaly processed, so i hope that i'll find help in here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Shell("C:\cygwin\Cygwin.bat")

SendKeys.Send("tracert -h " & _h & " " & domain.Text & " > temp" & i + 1 & ".txt"))

SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}")
```

this is the answer, icase anyone needed this.